# PHP Explode like functionality except when character falls anywhere between another set of characters

Tags: php, regex, explode

I want to convert the following string to an array

> [map]id=map,size=512x512,markers=[[latitude=40.5,longitude=-73.9],[latitude=41.5,longitude=-72.9]][/map]

I want to use the commas as delimiters but only if they do not fall somewhere between the [ and ] characters.

So, the above string would be converted to something like:

- [0] => id=map,
- [1] => size=512x512,
- [2] =>
  markers=[[latitude=40.5,longitude=-73.9],[latitude=41.5,longitude=-72.9]]

What would be the easiest way to achieve this?

I've looked at using the function str_getcsv but this only seems to work if the entire section is within the passed enclosure.

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to write your own parser which will do the job, let's imagine you have string like this: `id=map,size=512x512,markers=[[latitude=40.5,longitude=-73.9],[latitude=41.5,longitude=-72.9]]` (stripped `[map]` for shorter example):

```
$lastStart = 0; // Position where we last cut
$len = strlen( $str);
$openedBraces = 0; // Number of braces opened
$result = array();

for( $i = 0; $i < $len; $i++){
    switch( $str[$i]){
        // Handle opening brace
        case '[':
           $openedBraces++;
           break;

        // Handle closing brace
        case ']':
           $openedBraces--; // You may want to check negative numbers
           break;

        // Handle coma (it's sane operation only if there are no braces opened)
        case ',':
           if( $openedBraces == 0){
               $result[] = substr( $str, $lastStart, $i-$lastStart);
               $lastStart = $i+1;
           }
           break;
    }
}

$result[] = substr( $str, $lastStart);
```

Working [codepad.org](http://codepad.org/Cz5bsHkx) example.

Comment: Damn, that was fast. My code would've looked exactly the same except for variable names :D. However, I would suggest throwing an exception if `]` is encountered at `$openedBraces == 0` and if after the loop `$openedBraces > 0`.

Comment: Also note that you could precede this by `preg_match_all('~\[map](.*?)\[/map\]~si', $input, $matches)`, to take care of finding all those `map`s in an input string (then loop over `$matches[1]` and use every element as a `$str` in your code)

Comment: @m.buettner or by using `$lastStart = 5; $i = 5; $len -= 6;` :) Much more effective way.

Comment: Sure. My assumption was, that his actual input might contain more than just this single `map` tag, because otherwise what's the point of enclosing your actual data in a tag?